# Pedals as external effects

Tags: effects

I recently picked up some pedals along with a Mackie Vlz 802.

I was hoping to integrate the pedals with the mackie, and in turn, use them as external effects in Live. I'm aware that I have to connect the mixer to the nio (my interface) by connecting the tape outs on the mackie, to the inputs on the nio. I'm using the outputs 1-2 on the nio for monitoring.

I'm getting lost in relation to integrating the pedals with the mackie, to Ableton. I'm aware that I could connect the pedals by using the outputs and inputs of the nio, but that means I won't be able to integrate the mackie mixer, as well.

The mixer is great because it allows more inputs for some of my external gear, but i'd love to be able to use some pedals as external effects with Live.

Has anyone any ideas of setting this up? How do I setup an external affect in Ableton?

I'm sorry if this is really basic, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Al.

Here is a picture of the Mackie:

http://www.thomann.de/ie/prod_bdb_AR_20 ... ml?image=0

Here's a picture of the Nio:
http://www.thomann.de/ie/prod_bdb_AR_13 ... ml?image=7

Answer (score 1):

Well, your Mackie mixer has an ALT-Out and an aux-out. So connect your external effects to either the alt-out or the aux-out and route them back in via one of the channel input (or via the aux-return).

(If you use guitar-effect pedals, you will need something to match the impendance, a cheap DI box will work , even if it is not the best solution)

Answer (score 0):

I've always been curious about this from a sound design perspective - using pedals creatively instead of in-the-box or rack effects. How does it affect your workflow? I find anything that adds extra steps to the creative process is an inhibitor to experimentation, so I've never bothered throwing up pedals or making the investment.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently bought this Line 6 Bass pod xt live and I've been thinking of using it just to see what I can create. Unfortunately, haven't had the time to do that... I promise once I do, I'll let you know.